# Getting error on invoking lambda through terraform after deployment. And finding no logs in Cloudwatch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My lambda file in python looks like this:
**greet_lambda.py**

```
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return "{} from Lambda!".format(os.environ['greeting'])
```

My **main.tf file** is successfully deployed through `terraform apply` and looks like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}
provider "aws" {
   region = "us-east-1"
}
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
    name = "lambda_role"
    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
   function_name = "greet_lambda"
   s3_bucket = "dirai-terraform-lambda"
   s3_key    = "v1.0.0/greet_lambda.zip"
   handler = "greet_lambda.lambda_handler"
   runtime = "python3.7"
   role = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
}
```

On invoking the lambda greet_lambda.py through the below command I get an error in `output.txt` file and no logs are generated in cloudwatch

```
$aws lambda invoke --region=us-east-1 --function-name=greet_lambda output.txt
```

Error in `output.txt`

```
{"errorMessage": "'greeting'", "errorType": "KeyError", "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/greet_lambda.py\", line 4, in lambda_handler\n    return \"{} from Lambda!\".format(os.environ['greeting'])\n", "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/os.py\", line 681, in __getitem__\n    raise KeyError(key) from None\n"]}
```

Please advice where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.environ['greeting']` tries to fetch lambda's [environment variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html) called `greeting`. Your `test_lambda` does **not have** any such variables, defined using [environment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#variables).

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with your lambda code, but maybe you are after:

```
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return "{} from Lambda!".format('greeting')
```

Update

To add managed policy use [managed_policy_arns](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#managed_policy_arns)

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
    name = "lambda_role"

    managed_policy_arns = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"]

    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Marcin again! I am a little lost indeed in this exercise with Udacity's AWS Nanodegree course. And pointing out the gaps would sound excuses so I'll reserve it for a one to one feedback to them. However your answer made me revisit my main.tf file and I updated it with :
environment {
    variables = {
      greeting = "Hello Lambda+Terraform"
    }
  }

This works as a charm. Though there is a lot for me to catch up what is happening under the hood.

Comment: I still don't get the logs in Cloudwatch. Any clue why?

Comment: @raikumardipak No problem. CW logs is probably due to not adding `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` to your lambda role.

Comment: Where should I add it in the below section:
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
    name = "lambda_role"
    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

Comment: @raikumardipak I updated the answer. You can have a look.

Comment: Thank you again Marcin! I did have a look. And it again works like a charm. I also looked up the link at terraform website and understood what it is supposed to do. Lemme know when you are in India post this pandemic. I owe you a drink! Thank you again!

Comment: @Marcin Did not know about `managed_policy_arns`. Learned something. Have been using attachments like an animal :P Thank you :)